# Как импортировать бибилиотеку из GitHub?

Tags: android, github, java

Как импортировать бибилиотеку не .JAR формата? например из GitHub нужно импортировать [вот это](https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh/tree/master/extras/actionbarcompat) , я скачал себе проект, а как импортировать дальше в свой проект?

Comment: что такое WorkSpace ? Этот папка проекта, там где лежат папки src, res, манифест и т.д.? Я делаю так, нажимаю add и там пусто

Comment: Среда у меня Eclipse

Answer (score 1):

Добавляете в WorkSpace этот проект.

Затем правой кнопкой на ваш проект -> Properties -> Вкладка Android -> Там внизу Library -> Жмёте Add и выбираете проект ActionBar, который до этого в WorkSpace добавили.

Comment: для начала бы, узнали какая среда у человека, а уже потом говорили бы куда нажимать. (ну или укажите в какой конкретно среде искать ваш WorkSpace)